# What's the difference between an user defined attribute and non user defined attribute?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have an customer attribute defined as follows:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "attr_code",  [
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Attribute Label",
            "input"    => "text",
            "source"   => "Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default"  => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"   => false,
            "note"     => "",
            'system'   => 0,
            'user_defined' => true
]);
```

My question is: what's the difference on the attribute if I set `user_defined` to `false`? And in which situations I should set `user_defined` to `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually Magento user_defined = false attributes are known as system attributes. 
So Magento has some of their system attribute, which we can not delete from admin panel. So magento won't allow system  attribute to be deleted. We can delete them through database but it is not safe.

So Attributes which are highly required to run a system that type of attribute we can create as system attributes. 
But in opposite side, we can easily delete user defined attributes from admin panel.

Hope it helps 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Magento system attributes are set to `false` for **user_defined** so our custom attributes should be set to `true`. System attributes can not be deleted so if you set `false` to **user_defined**, your attribute will work as system attribute.

Comment: So you mean it's just for indication, no real differences between them?

Answer (score 4):

To add to this:

If you add attributes via `Install-/ UpdateSchema` make sure to add to `'user_defined' => true`. Only non system attributes (eg. is_user_defined = 1) can be used for configurable products.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I notice a big difference when I learnt **Magento 1**. If an attribute is set to be **user_defined = true**, it then won't be created in table **eav_entity_attribute**. But still you can find it in table **eav_attribute**. If set **user_defined = false**, then when it's created it will appear in both **eav_entity_attribute** and **eav_attribute** tables. But in return, I don't know why this make the difference / affect.

I'm not sure about Magento 2, but I guess you can verify it easily and let others know.

Answer (score 1):

If an attribute is set as 'user_defined' then a user may define the option values inside the attribute user interface.

However if you are using a source model then 'user_defined' must be set to false, otherwise the options from the source model are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

**user_defined** = ***true*** attributes are generally created by catalog manager to have product specific information.
**user_defined** = ***false*** for Magento default attributes which are required for some functionalities to work or any module providing some additional feature based on attribute, like *sku*, *qty*, *website_ids*, *product_online* are system attributes required to manage quantity and scope of product, same way is_featured or *show_on_homepage* can be some attribute doing something in backend to provide some feature and shouldn't be deleted by admin user that may break the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that user defined does is that it determines if you can edit or not the options of the attribute from the attribute edit page in back office, therefor if you have an attribute with specific labels that you do not want an admin user to change, you should set "user_defined" to false.