# Assign Attribute to only specific attribute set Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

Here's my code:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
            $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
        } 

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

                // CREATE ATTRIBUTE SET 
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'NewAttributeSet', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

                // CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'text_new',
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'New Text',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                    'source' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 5,
                    'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'attribute_set_id' => 'NewAttributeSet',
            ]
        );  

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

} ?>
```

All working fine but the attribute is assigning to all attribute set and I want on only one attribute set which I have created: NewAttributeSet

Comment: >try to change **attribute_set_id** to 'attribute_set'

Answer (score 14):

To prevent Magento 2 from adding your attribute to all attribute sets (as of Magento 2.3.1):

- You **must** set `'user_defined' => true,` in the array passed to `addAttribute()`.
- You **must not** define a `group` key in the array, otherwise Magento will add your attribute, in the specified group, to all attribute sets.
- You don't need to define an `attribute_set_id` key (nor `attribute_set`). It doesn't do anything.
- You don't need to specify a `sort_order` key. It is only used when Magento adds the attribute to all attribute sets.
- You need to call `addAttributeToGroup()` after `addAttribute()` to add it to the attribute set you want.

The code would look like this:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'text_new',
    [
        'user_defined' => true,
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'New Text',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
    ]
);

$eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'NewAttributeSet',
    'General', // group
    'text_new',
    5 // sort order
);
```

Comment: Thnx a lot for your post ;)

Answer (score 2):

When an attribute gets created with `addAttribute()` and a group is specified or the attribute should not be a user defined attribute, Magento will add the attribute to all attribute sets with the same entity type (catalog_product). I don't have any clue why, though.

So if you would like to create a non user defined attribute you can first create the attribute as user defined and the change it to not user defined:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'text_new',
    [
                                  // id required, not name of set!
        'attribute_set_id'        => $attributeSet->getAttributeSetId(),
                                  // temporarily!
        'user_defined'            => true,     
                                  // don't yet assign to group!    
        'group'                   => '',

// ----- your other parameters ---------------- 
        'type'                    => 'varchar',
        'label'                   => 'New Text',
        'backend'                 => '',
        'input'                   => 'text',
        'wysiwyg_enabled'         => false,
        'source'                  => '',
        'required'                => false,
        'sort_order'              => 5,
        'global'                  => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front'        => true,            
    ]
);
$eavSetup->updateAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'text_new', 'is_user_defined', false);

// Assign attribute now to groups if you need to ...
```

Note the difference between 'user_defined' and 'is_user_defined' when the attibutes gets created and updated.

Difference between user and non user defined attribute is discussed [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/whats-the-difference-between-an-user-defined-attribute-and-non-user-defined-att).

---

### Implementation of `addAttribute()` in EavSetup:

```
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);

    $data = array_replace(
        ['entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId, 'attribute_code' => $code],
        $this->attributeMapper->map($attr, $entityTypeId)
    );

    $this->_validateAttributeData($data);

    $sortOrder = isset($attr['sort_order']) ? $attr['sort_order'] : null;
    $attributeId = $this->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, 'attribute_id');
    if ($attributeId) {
        $this->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeId, $data, null, $sortOrder);
    } else {
        $this->_insertAttribute($data);
    }

    if (!empty($attr['group']) || empty($attr['user_defined'])) {
        $select = $this->setup->getConnection()->select()->from(
            $this->setup->getTable('eav_attribute_set')
        )->where(
            'entity_type_id = :entity_type_id'
        );
        $sets = $this->setup->getConnection()->fetchAll($select, ['entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId]);
        foreach ($sets as $set) {
            if (!empty($attr['group'])) {
                $this->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $set['attribute_set_id'], $attr['group']);
                $this->addAttributeToSet(
                    $entityTypeId,
                    $set['attribute_set_id'],
                    $attr['group'],
                    $code,
                    $sortOrder
                );
            } else {
                $this->addAttributeToSet(
                    $entityTypeId,
                    $set['attribute_set_id'],
                    $this->_generalGroupName,
                    $code,
                    $sortOrder
                );
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($attr['option']) && is_array($attr['option'])) {
        $option = $attr['option'];
        $option['attribute_id'] = $this->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $code);
        $this->addAttributeOption($option);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's working example for Magento 2.3.2:

Use

> Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup -> $eavSetup

```
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
            'some_cool_product_attribute',
            [
                'user_defined' => true,
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Some cool attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
            ]
        );
```

Then for example if you want assign this attribute to Default set and Content group
you should do:

```
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
             $eavSetup->getAttributeSetId(ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE, 'Default'),
            'Content',
            'some_cool_product_attribute',
            5
        );
```

As result you'll get this attribute in admin:
[image: Attribute in admin panel]

[image: Attribute in another attribute set]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One, Check the New Code Added.**

```
<?php
  namespace Demo\Mymodule\Setup;

  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {
      private $eavSetupFactory;
      private $attributeSetFactory;
      private $attributeSet;
      private $categorySetupFactory;

      public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
          {
              $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
              $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
              $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
          } 

      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
          $setup->startSetup();

                  // CREATE ATTRIBUTE SET 
          $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
          $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
          $data = [
              'attribute_set_name' => 'NewAttributeSet', 
              'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
              'sort_order' => 200,
          ];
          $attributeSet->setData($data);
          $attributeSet->validate();
          $attributeSet->save();
          $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
          $attributeSet->save();

          /*************** New Code Start ***************/
          $attribute_group = 'New Attribute Group Job'; 
          $this->eavSetupFactory->addAttributeGroup(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $attributeSetId, $attribute_group);
          /*************** New Code End ***************/

                  // CREATE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE
          $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

              $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                  'text_new',
                  [
                      'type' => 'varchar',
                      'label' => 'New Text',
                      'backend' => '',
                      'input' => 'text',
                      'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                      'source' => '',
                      'required' => false,
                      'sort_order' => 5,
                      'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                      'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                      'visible_on_front' => true,
                      'attribute_set_id' => 'NewAttributeSet',
              ]
          );  

          /*************** New Code Start ***************/
          $this->eavSetupFactory->addAttributeToSet(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,$attributeSetId,$attribute_group,'text_new',null);
          /*************** New Code End ***************/

          $setup->endSetup();
      }

  } 

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the below line

> 'attribute_set_id' => 'NewAttributeSet',

to

> 'attribute_set' =>  'AttributeSetName',

Now your attribute get assigned to above mentioned attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sébastien's answer there is actually an exception for `user_defined`. To set `user_defined` to false it should be provided with the value `"\x00"`.

This works because the value is checked using `empty()`, which will return true for the value `false`, to see if the attribute needs to be added to all attribute sets. The value `"\x00"`, which is a string containing null in hexadecimal, will have `empty()` return false yet convert to `0` when written to the database.