# How to create morethan oneproduct attribute and assign it to specific attribute set-Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, patches, setup

I have an attributeset named **dealz** and attribute set group with name **DealzInformation**.Also I have some customproductattributes like **dealdate,dealqty,dealprize**...etc. Then how to show this group with customattribute for only this attributeset.

Answer (score 0):

Refrence: [Assign Attribute to only specific attribute set Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201966/assign-attribute-to-only-specific-attribute-set-magento-2)

```
$eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'dealz',// attributeset
            'DealzInformation', // group
            'dealdate'//attributes
        );
```