# What is the distinction between defining a customer attribute as "system" versus not "user defined"?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, eav, customer-attribute

### General Context

When adding custom attributes to EAV-storage data types such as `customer`s and `customer_address`es, two seemingly redundant configuration values are allowed to be passed in:

```
// File: InstallData.php

public function install(...) {
    /** @var Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(...);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY,
        'my_custom_attr',
        [
            'system'       => true,
            'user_defined' => false
        ]
    );
}
```

[Other questions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/) have addressed the question of what exactly a `user_defined` custom attribute means: the attribute is considered a "system" attribute (note the ambiguous terminology here), and as such it will not appear on the admin as removable because it is considered essential to the operation of Magento.

### Specific Context

However, when omitting the `system` and `user_defined` configuration values altogether, I found that the attributes I defined defaulted to `'system' => true` and `'user_defined' => false`. This behavior seems to be due to the following two lines of code in `PropertyMapper.php` files:

```
// File: Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Setup/PropertyMapper.php
// Line: 27
'is_system' => $this->_getValue($input, 'system', 1),

// ...

// File: Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup/PropertyMapper.php
// Line: 35
'is_user_defined' => $this->_getValue($input, 'user_defined', 0),
```

Based on the location of the two aforementioned files, I would predict that `is_system` relates specifically to customer attributes, and `is_user_defined` relates to attributes of any entity type.

When I later attempted to set and save those attributes via a repository, as such:

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface */
$address = $this->addressRepository->getById(...);
$address->setCustomAttribute('my_custom_attr', 'my_custom_value');
$this->addressRepository->save($address);
```

...I found that my custom attribute was not even exposed by the engine, due to the following lines of code:

```
// File: Magento/Customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php
// Lines: 121-143
public function getCustomAttributesMetadata($dataObjectClassName = AddressMetadataInterface::DATA_INTERFACE_NAME)
{
    ...
    foreach ($this->getAllAttributesMetadata() as $attributeMetadata) {
        ...
        if (!$isDataObjectMethod && !$attributeMetadata->isSystem()) {
            $customAttributes[] = $attributeMetadata;
        }
    }
}
```

(The link to the Magento source is [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/83a9b9c9fbf86e263f5ef2617493b0249632541e/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php#L137).)

I had to set `'system' => false` in my `InstallData.php` script in order for the custom attribute to be accessible via the program, yet I left `user_defined` untouched.

### Question

**What is the difference between these two configuration values from a human perspective? How do they affect each other, if at all?**