# Magento 2 Attribute Property - How 'user_defined' and 'system' attribute propety are different?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.4.4

***'system'*** attribute property tells if attribute is system defined or not.

***'user_defined'*** attribute property tells if attribute is custom (define by developer) or not.

It means, if *'system'=0*, the attribute is *'user_defined'* and vice versa.

So why *Magento 2* uses two property (system, user_defined) for the same reason ? If they are different then how ?

Answer (score 0):

`system` and `user_defined` attribute properties are different and do different jobs. In the database, `system` attribute property save in `is_system` column and `user_defined` attribute property save in `is_user_defined` column.

Especially, `system` attribute property is only used for **Customer entity** (`customer_eav_attribute` table) while `user_defined` is used for all entities (`eav_attribute` table).

You can check `prefix` attribute, which has `system` value is **0** and `user_defined` value is **0** to confirm 'system' = 0 does not mean the attribute is 'user_defined'.

Magento uses `system` attribute property to define whether an attribute is a **custom** attribute or **system** attribute.

While Magento uses `user_defined` attribute property to define whether an attribute is an attribute defined by the user or system attribute (not the `system` attribute property mentioned above).

See how Magento uses both `system` (**isSystem()**) and `user_defined` (**isUserDefined()**) attribute properties in `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php`, method `getCustomerAccountData()`.

See how Magento uses `system` attribute property in:

- vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php, method `getCustomerAccountData()`.
- vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/CustomerMetadata.php, method `getCustomAttributesMetadata`.
- vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/AddressMetadata.php, method `getCustomAttributesMetadata()`.

See how Magento uses `user_defined` attribute property in:

- vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php, method `getCustomerAccountData()`.
- vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php, method `getAddressFromData`.
- vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php, method `extractAddress()`.
- vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/Form.php, method `getUserAttributes` and `getSystemAttributes`.
- vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php, method `extractAddress()`.

Comment: thanks for the response Tu. my question is why we're using two property for the same job ? system = 0 and user_defined = 1 OR system =1 and user_defined = 0...either we can use system or user_defined for the job. how both are different ?

Comment: @WakarAhamad I've updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually, Magento **`user_defined = false`** attributes are known as system attributes. So Magento has some of their system attribute, which we **can not delete** from the admin panel. So Magento won't allow system attributes to be deleted. We can delete them through the database but it is not safe.

### **OR**

1. **`user_defined = false`** for Magento default attributes which are required for some functionalities to work or any module providing some additional feature based on an attribute, like SKU, qty, website_ids, product_online are system attributes required to manage quantity and scope of product, same way is_featured or show_on_homepage can be some attribute doing something in the backend to provide some feature and shouldn't be deleted by admin user that may break the functionality.

### AND

2. **`user_defined = true`** attributes are generally created by the catalog managers to have product specific information. So Admin users **can delete** these attributes from the admin panel.

For more infomation check below link.

**[What's the difference between an user defined attribute and non user defined attribute?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/whats-the-difference-between-an-user-defined-attribute-and-non-user-defined-att)**

**`Thanks.`**